# Get start and end timing of application in android for ionic application

Tags: android, typescript, kotlin, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to get the start timing and end timing of other application from android device for analysis of personal behaviour and use it in our application. Can anyone suggest how to get those data. Is there any API or any framework to get these kind of data. Our ionic application version is Ionic 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use platfrom.pause to detect if the user has put the app in the background and platform.resume if the app has opened again. See more [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/platform#usage)

```
this.platform.pause.subscribe(async () => {
  // send data (like timestamp) to BE server
});
this.platform.resume.subscribe(async () => {
  // send data (like timestamp) to BE server
});
```

**However**, I recommend using **Firebase + Analytics**. You will get a much more accurate analysis of personal behavior of your users. Full tutorial [here](https://devdactic.com/firebase-analytics-ionic/)